# prob in using == for comparing 2 string

Tags: c++

i want to know similarity between two linked list  i got some same data between them but == operator can not recognized them can u help me? v will always stays at 0  data type is string

```
class node{
string Data;
node *next;
};

 float nodelinkedlist::vazn(nodelinkedlist list1,nodelinkedlist list2)
{
 float w=0,v=0;
node *temp1=new node;
node *temp2=new node;
temp1->next=list1.first->next;
temp1->Data=list1.first->Data;
temp2->next=list2.first->next;
temp2->Data=list2.first->Data;
      while(temp1->next!=NULL)
  { 
    while(temp2->next!=NULL)
    {
        if((temp1->Data)==(temp2->Data))
            v++;
        temp2=temp2->next;
    }
    temp1=temp1->next;
}
w=(v/((linklen(list1)+linklen(list2)-v)));
return w;
}
```

Comment: What is the type of the `Data` member?

Comment: Please, reduce and expand your code to a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Mat  sry for not mentioning data is a string

Comment: Remember that string comparison is case *sensitive*. The string `"FOO"` is not equal to the string `"foo"`.

Comment: You might want to run in a debugger, and step through the function line by line, to see the actual values of the variables and members involved.

Comment: Print the strings you're comparing so you're sure that you're comparing what you think you're comparing. Also use pen and paper to draw the pointers as you walk through the code "by hand" (hint: pay attention to `temp2`). And watch out for those memory leaks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Depending on the libraries used the == operator might not be implemented. Here's are some references:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/

try this comparison instead:

```
if(temp1->Data.compare(temp2->Data)) == 0)
     v++;
```

Where the comparison returns a ***0*** if the strings are equal, just remember to to factor in case sensitivity.

Another issue i just noticed, is when you complete the inner loop, you don't reset the value of the temp2 node.

```
class node{
string Data;
node *next;
};

 float nodelinkedlist::vazn(nodelinkedlist list1,nodelinkedlist list2)
{
 float w=0,v=0;
 node *temp1=new node;
 node *temp2=new node;
 temp1->next=list1.first->next;
 temp1->Data=list1.first->Data;
 temp2->next=list2.first->next;
 temp2->Data=list2.first->Data;
  while(temp1->next!=NULL)
  { 
      while(temp2->next!=NULL)
      {
          if(temp1->Data.compare(temp2->Data)) == 0)
              v++;
          temp2=temp2->next;
      }
      temp1=temp1->next;
      temp2->next=list2.first->next;
      temp2->Data=list2.first->Data;
  }
  w=(v/((linklen(list1)+linklen(list2)-v)));
  return w;
}
```

Comment: ty its better than == and dos not skip any file seems like operator == skips some files and cant recognized them